# How do I center this HTML button and ensure its position does not change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a button that generates a random Chuck Norris fact with the Chuck Norris API.

I've attempted to centre the button itself and the h3 element where the fact is generated. However, as different facts are generated each time the button is clicked (some facts are short and some are very long) the 'Generate' button gets shifted up and down.

I want to keep make sure this button remains static with each fact being generated below it.

```js
async function generate() {

  const getdata = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
  const response = await getdata.json();

  document.querySelector("h3").innerText = response.value;

}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning button" onclick="generate()">GENERATE</button>
  <h3 class="info"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to keep the button and the text centered, I don't see how you can do that while also keeping the button fixed. If the button is fixed in place and the text changes in length, it won't always be centered

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to wrap the content in a div, and give it a height. the fixed height stops the movement, as it is not centring an auto-height div.

This approach comes with a warning, if the fact is larger than the wrapper, it will overflow out, below the div. So depending on what else is going on in the page, you may have to pad, or be aware of that.

```js
async function generate (){
    const getdata = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
    const response = await getdata.json();

    document.querySelector("h3").innerText = response.value;

}
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chuck Norris Random</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning button" onclick="generate()">GENERATE</button> 
          <h3 class="info"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, as I'm a bit new to web dev could you pls explain how responsive this solution will be since you're using px for the height?

Comment: @Biggeez Sure, you can test out the responsive aspect here. Just generate a big quote, and you'll see that it makes a scrollbar.

Comment: in this scenario, what would be the difference in using em or rem instead?

Comment: You can use whatever metric you like. The reason it is working is because the height is fixed. So when a new quote comes in, the box does not change height - so there is not jump. The down fall to this approach is if you put content beneath it, and the quote is too big, the text will overflow onto it. However, this isn't in your example - so I didn't worry about it, or complicate anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that removing justify-content: center can help

Comment: can you explain how that helps?

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the ways you can achieve this:

```js
async function generate (){

    const getdata = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
    const response = await getdata.json();

    document.querySelector("h3").innerText = response.value;

}
```

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container > button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning button" onclick="generate()">GENERATE</button>

      <h3 class="info"></h3>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid for this with place-items property set to center.

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: maybe have a look at this https://codepen.io/una/pen/YzyYbBx